# Image.FromFile ошибка

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, библиотеки

Я загружаю изображение таким способом

```
Image _img = Image.FromFile("C:/...Puzzle/Img/444.jpg");
```

При попытке загрузить изображение без указания полного пути вылетает exeption

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: 444.jpg
```

Как можно загрузить изображение без указания пути до него?

Answer (score 1):

Можно указывать относительный путь. Например относительно основного приложения можно указать так:

```
Image _img = Image.FromFile("..\\Puzzle\\Img\\444.jpg");
```

Данный способ указывает программе путь к каталогу который находится выше программы и в котором есть каталог `Puzzle`.

Живой пример будет таким:

```
var applicationFolder = "C:\\ProgramFolder";
var fileName = "C:\\Puzzle\\Img\\444.jpg";
// или так, относительно программы
fileName = "..\\Puzzle\\Img\\444.jpg";
```

Либо указав полный путь, или с использованием системный переменных.
Любой другой способ будет приводить к ошибке.